# Mac hardware to write Codename One native interfaces

Tags: codenameone

I need a Mac to write a native Codename One interface for iOS.  I would like to use it in the future for the same purpose.  I need to be able to open with Xcode the native code generated by the build server, add the implementation in Objective-C of the native methods and test the code on my iPhone X, to connect to the Mac via usb.

I found the following refurbished computer, I would like to ask you a secure confirmation that it goes well for the above purposes, before buying it:

Model MacBook Pro 13″ (MacBookPro9,2) - A1278 - MD101LL/A - 2012

Intel Core i5 3210M "Ivy Bridge" 2.5GHz "Ivy Bridge" processor with turbo boost up to 3.1GHz

Installed Ram 8 GB PC3-12800 (1600 MHz) DDR3 SO-DIMM

Intel HD Graphics 4000 integrated video card - 1.5GB of shared video memory

Installed Hard Disk Drive 500GB SATA 2.5″ HDD

13.3 inch (diagonal) LED backlit display - 1280×800 pixels

Operating System macOS 10.15 Catalina

Keyboard Layout QWERTY US - International

2x USB 3.0, 2x Thunderbolt, 1x SD-card slot, 1x Jack 3.5″ Devices

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about software, but about hardware recommendation

Comment: It's a valid point. It is about the hardware requirements to develop a specific open source software tool so I'm not sure where else a question like this would fit?
Maybe it can be migrated by a moderator to https://apple.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now seems OK, my one serious concern is the SATA disk and not SSD. Up until recently I used the 2013 version with 16gb, SSD and i7 which is still a great machine (screen broke in a fall on hard tile floor).

I can't tell if it will work well in the future but for now the important line is:

> Operating System macOS 10.15 Catalina

That's the latest. So it will be able to run the latest xcode which should be compatible for Codename One development for a while.

Since this is an 8 year old machine and Apple is transitioning to ARM devices don't expect more than 2 years from this machine though.

Another option you can consider is a Mac mini. They are often an amazing value for the money, even when new.